# Change owner of the home ~ folder from 503 to my user

Tags: macos, permission, root

I used to use 2 users: admin and user for work. Today I set my user access to admin laptop and deleted the previous admin user. Now, the owner of my home folder is 503. I cannot do anything in my root folder. How can I change my ~ folder ownership to my user

Comment: What was the UID of the user you deleted? - I suspect the easiest thing is restore your Mac to the state it was in before you deleted the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

1. `cd ../` from the root (you will be on the Users folder).
2. `sudo chown -R your_username:your_user_grop` (you can check it out in System Preferences -> Users & Groups -> (right click on your user) Advanced Options).
   This helped me : )